# Material-ui: Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Toolbar'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Material UI code

I am using React Material ui. Tried to use ToolBar and AppBar component of Material UI. But while using this i got the following error.Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Toolbar'

I've done some research and removed the packages and reinstalled them. However, I keep getting the same error i tried to import using both the ways to import

Not sure why this issue happens.Is there any issue with the @material-ui/core version i am using ?

````
```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import {
    ListItem,
    IconButton,
    ListItemText,
    Avatar,
    Divider,
    List,
    Typography,
    Box
} from '@material-ui/core';
import {
    ArraowBack,
    AssignmentInd,
    Home,
    Apps,
    ContactMail,
    ArrowBack
} from "@material-ui/icons"

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <Box component="nav">
            <AppBar>
            <Toolbar>
                    <ArrowBack>

                    </ArrowBack>
                </Toolbar>  
            </AppBar>

        </Box>
    )
}

export default Navbar;

```
````

I am using React Material ui. Tried to use ToolBar and AppBar component of Material UI. But while using this i got the following error.Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Toolbar'

I've done some research and removed the packages and reinstalled them. However, I keep getting the same error i tried to import using both the ways to import

Not sure why this issue happens.Is there any issue with the @material-ui/core version i am using ?

Comment: Its `@material-ui/core/Toolbar`... Steps for debugging that should have been taken: 1) What's different about this component compared to the other ones that don't error? 2) How does the documentation show how to use this component?

Comment: Thank you I will take a note of your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

```
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
// or
import { Toolbar } from '@material-ui/core';
```